# Reading multiple atributes CouchDB with Java

Tags: java, couchdb

I am trying to read in the `couchDB`:

```
"coordinates": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
           -117.166272,
           32.714312
       ]
   },
```

I'm using `CouchDB4j` and normally I could read normal attributes with:

```
mydocument.containsKey("text")
```

But I can't use it for  "coordinates", as it has multiples attributes (type and coordinates).

It displays:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 net.sf.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
```

How could I resolve it, reading the coordinates and getting both point and coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried using version 2.4 of json-lib and it worked for me.  I used groovy as it was quicker to test with groovy:

```
// I had to manually download the jar using:
// curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/json-lib/json-lib/2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar >  ~/.groovy/grapes/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/jars/json-lib-2.4.jar

@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='net.sf.json-lib', module='json-lib', version='2.4')
)

import net.sf.json.*
import net.sf.json.groovy.*

builder = new net.sf.json.groovy.JsonGroovyBuilder()

def s = '''{
   "_id": "12345",
   "coordinates": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [
           -117.166272,
           32.714312
       ]
   },
   "foo": "bar"
}'''

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def doc = jsonSlurper.parseText(s)

assert doc.containsKey("coordinates") == true

assert doc.get("coordinates").toString() == 
       '{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-117.166275,32.714314]}'

assert doc.get("coordinates")['coordinates'][0] == -117.166275
```